# Read continues audio stream from socket

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, stream

I am making an app where I need to read continues stream of sound which is sent in the form of an byte array. The server side records sound like this (based on an example here on SO):

```
    // Get the minimum buffer size required for the successful creation of an AudioRecord object.
    int bufferSizeInBytes = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
            RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);
    bufferSizeInBytes = 30000;

    // Initialize Audio Recorder.
    _audio_recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
            RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSizeInBytes);

    // Start Recording.
    _audio_recorder.startRecording();

    int numberOfReadBytes = 0;
    byte audioBuffer[] = new byte[bufferSizeInBytes];
    boolean recording = false;
    float tempFloatBuffer[] = new float[3];
    int tempIndex = 0;
    byte totalByteBuffer[] = new byte[60 * 44100 * 2];
while (true)
{
    float totalAbsValue = 0.0f;
    short sample = 0;

    numberOfReadBytes = _audio_recorder.read(audioBuffer, 0, bufferSizeInBytes);

    for (int i = 0; i < bufferSizeInBytes; i += 2)
    {
        sample = (short) ((audioBuffer[i]) | audioBuffer[i + 1] << 8);
        totalAbsValue += Math.abs(sample) / (numberOfReadBytes / 2);
    }

    tempFloatBuffer[tempIndex % 3] = totalAbsValue;
    float temp = 0.0f;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        temp += tempFloatBuffer[i];

    if ((temp >= 0 && temp <= _sensitivity) && recording == false)
    {
        Log.i("TAG", "1");
        tempIndex++;
        continue;
    }

    if (temp > _sensitivity && recording == false)
    {
        Log.i("TAG", "2");
        recording = true;
    }

    if(temp < _sensitivity && recording == true)
    {
        recording = false;
        continue;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfReadBytes; i++)
        totalByteBuffer[i] = audioBuffer[i];

    if (prepare_sound(totalByteBuffer, numberOfReadBytes))
    {
        totalByteBuffer = new byte[60 * 44100 * 2];

        tempIndex++;
    }
}
```

The example this is taken from is recording sound and saves it to a file when there is no more sound to record. My goal on the other hand is to record sound when there is sound and send this sound on the fly when still recording. Hence, I want to send sounds right a way and not store it to a file when there is no more sound to record. So far I am taking the byte[] with data and stores it in an object an sends it to a client using ObjectOutputStream. The client will then create a temp sound file and play it using MediaPlayer. But I feel that this is not the most effect way to achieve my goal. So, is there any more efficient way to do this with respect to send an continues stream of data as media player does not support playing pure byte[] of data?

Thanks for any help and tips!

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the best solutions for me is to record the sound and when the buffer is full it is sent to the client side. The client then uses an AudioTrack instance to play the byte[] that contains the data like this:

```
public void onSoundReceived(byte[] sound)
{
    _audio_input_stream.write(sound, 0, sound.length);
}
```

This also makes the sound more "non-lagging" as this is not a MediaPlayer instance which will stop the sound after each time the data was done playing.